# numpy.subtract but only until difference reaches threshold - replace numbers smaller than that with threshold

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I want to subtract a given value from each element in my `numpy` array.
For example, if I have a numpy array called `a_q`, and variable called `subtract_me`, then I can simply do this:

```
result = np.subtract(a_q,subtract_me)
```

That's fine. But I don't want it to simply subtract blindly from every element. If the difference is lower than a threshold, then I don't want the subtraction to happen. Instead, I want that element of the array to be replaced by that threshold.

What's the most efficient way to do this? I could simply iterate through the array and subtract from each element and put a check condition on whether the threshold has been reached or not, and build a new array out of the results (as below) - but is there a better or more efficient way to do it?

```
threshold = 3 # in my real program, the threshold is the 
              # lowest non-infinity number that python can handle
subtract_me = 6
a_q = []
for i in range(10):
    val = i - subtract_me
    if val < threshold:
        val = threshold
    a_q.append(val)

myarr = np.array(a_q)
print myarr
```

Comment: Take a look at the numpy `clip` function/method (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

Answer (score 2):

Vectorised methods are typically most efficient with NumPy arrays so here's one way which is likely to be more efficient than iterating over an array one element at a time:

```
>>> threshold = 3
>>> subtract_me = 6
>>> a_q = np.arange(10)

>>> arr = a_q - subtract_me # takeaway the subtract_me value
array([-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])

>>> arr[arr - subtract_me < threshold] = threshold # replace any value less than threshold
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

EDIT: since [`np.clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) was mentioned in the comments below the question, I may as well absorb it into my answer for completeness ;-)

Here's one way you could use it to get the desired result:

```
>>> np.clip((a_q - subtract_me), threshold, np.max(a_q))
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: I think he needs something like `arr[arr - subtract_me < threshold] -= subtract_me`

Comment: @SaulloCastro - apologies if I've misunderstood your comment, but `arr[arr - subtract_me < threshold] -= subtract_me` gives a result different to the OP's example. It doesn't replace a value below the threshold with `threshold` as requested.